# Can not print using report viewer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing, report-viewer2010

I have a problem with my printers. I write an c# .net application. I used report viewer (rdlc file) to view and print reports. It have worked fine, but in these days my printers can not print directly, I must press ok button on printer. This situation does not happen with all printer, just 2 printer (hp 2050 and hp 1006).
Thank for your supporting.

Comment: maybe replace your printer accordingly to work with your application :)

Comment: you mean it problem because of the printer? I wonder it may happen because windows update?

Comment: but this problem does not happen when i print by ms work, excel or any thing except rdlc report